# Android Debugger (on Netbeans7)

Tags: android, debugging, netbeans, adb

I just started using the `ADB Log` yesterday (Window -> Output -> ADB Log) and it showed me where my error was coming from as debuggers should. However, when I started it up today it won't show anything other than `Error - No devices found` then it tries to reconnect in 10 seconds. Eventually it just states that the device is offline.

I have the emulator up and running and replicated the error I had yesterday but still nothing useful from the debugger shows up. I haven't changed anything since yesterday and am not sure why I'm having the issue.

Does anyone know of any possible fixes?

Comment: Sorry I am only familiar with Eclipse - deleted my answer

Comment: @Jack the answer could be relevant if it's not Netbeans dependent. I'm just not sure why it can't find the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick tip (this may or may not solve your problem): In your DDMS view, if the device isn't selected (in the left list of devices with their running processes), then nothing will display in logcat.

Also sometimes I have to run the following command when adb starts acting buggy:

adb kill-server
adb start-server (or adb devices)

EDIT: This is for Eclipse - not sure about Netbeans

Also: I have found that some cables do not work with debugging, only charging (these are cheaper cables). I had something like the same issue, once I used a better cable it started working.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I checked my list of devices and the one I'm using is selected so that isn't the issue. I couldn't quite find where to kill/start the adb server though

Comment: Dos prompt - or linux prompt. If using windows, generally its in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools or something similar.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure where it was located. Thanks, that seemed to do the trick! It still attempts to reconnect from time to time though. But perhaps I can keep it working long enough to get my work done :)